# The router file doen't get return result on koajs, nodejs

Tags: node.js, koa

I got puzzled on the router on koajs, e.g. there're two files, one is the main file `app.js`, code like following

```
//some codes
const home = require("./router/home.js");
router.use("/", home.routes());
```

and another is router file `home.js`, code like following

```
router
    .get("/:rel", async (ctx) => {
        console.log("run sub");
    })
    .get("/", async (ctx) => {
        console.log("run root");
    })
module.exports = router;
```

I thought `http://localhost:3000/` can return the console log `run root`, that's right, and `http://localhost:3000/dlkjf` can return `run sub`, but it's not, there's no return result, if I update `home.js` to

```
 router
    .get("/:rel", async (ctx) => {
        console.log("run sub");
    })
module.exports = router;
```

Still got nothing, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I updated `app.js` to `router.use(home.routes());` that will work, why?

Answer (score 2):

It's about `module.exports` property that you set its value at the end of the `home.js`:

```
module.exports = router;
```

you should pass the router like this:

```
module.exports = {router};
```

or at `app.js` use it as follow:

```
const routes = require("./router/home.js");
router.use("/", routes());
```